# What's the difference between payable function and non-payable function in bytecode for solidity?

Tags: solidity, payable

Suppose I have two solidity functions:

```
function funcA()public{}
```

And

```
function funcB()public payable{}
```

What's the difference between their bytecode?
if I call the funcA with some ether in the transaction, it will revert, and what happens in bytecode?

Comment: Can you clarify your question please? are you trying to recognize payable and non-payable function by looking at the bytecode?

Comment: yes，that is what I want。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning a non-payable function will execute `CALLVALUE` and revert if it returns a non-zero value.

For example:

```
Assembly                 | Pseudocode
---------------------------------------------
  CALLVALUE              |
  DUP1                   |
  ISZERO                 |  if (msg.value == 0)
  PUSH2 label            |
  JUMPI                  |    goto label
  PUSH1 00               |
  DUP1                   |
  REVERT                 |  revert("")
```